# Getting a Countdown based on new Date() to Stop Counting Down on the Hour

Tags: javascript, iframe, countdown

Okay, so I'm working on a countdown that counts down to the top of every hour and then loads new content in a frame under it.

Because I'm using new Date, I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the countdown stop at the top of the hour, rather than just starting again.  Because of that, I tell the page to load the new frame content.  I had thought of dropping a cookie, but would rather keep this all self-contained and can't help but think I'm overlooking something very obvious.

Here's the code, I'm using at the moment. (It's messy because I've been trying a lot of different solutions and haven't cleaned it up)  Let me know what you think I could do to fix this.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var now = new Date();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var hours = "00";
  var days = "00";
  return {
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': 60 - minutes - 1,
    'seconds': 60 - seconds
  };


}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var now = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = now.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + now.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + now.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + now.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (now.minutes + now.seconds < 1) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('clockdiv').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("welcomemsg").innerHTML = "The Video is Now Playing";
      frames['videoplayer'].location.href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/0l1BxXBlODo?autoplay=1'
      } else { 
      document.getElementById("welcomemsg").innerHTML = "Hold Your Horses, it's not time for the video yet.";
}
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Let me know what you think.

Thanks!

EDIT: I worked out a solution that seems to work.  I replaced the final if statement with the following:

```
    if (now.minutes == 0 && now.seconds <= 1 ) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('clockdiv').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("welcomemsg").innerHTML = "The Video is Now Playing";
      frames['videoplayer'].location.href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/0l1BxXBlODo?autoplay=1'
      } else { 
      document.getElementById("welcomemsg").innerHTML = "Hold Your Horses, it's not time for the video yet.";
}
```

Hopefully this helps people with a similar issue in the future.  Like I said, I KNEW I was missing something simple, and I was.

-Nick

Comment: `now.minutes == 0 && now.seconds <= 1` – are you expecting negative seconds to occur, or why aren’t you comparing them to 0 as well? And btw., this might fail in certain situations. setInterval does not guarantee precision down to the millisecond, stuff like the browser being very busy might cause delays, and so seconds might be “skipped” effectively. Now if that should occur exactly then, when you expect it to be 0 min 0 secs on the full hour, your counter would keep running. I’d rather store the current hour value when you start the timer, and then compare to that.

Comment: The seconds will never actually become zero, the moment that it becomes zero, the time tolls over to the next hour.